# Clean uninstall of virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: software-center, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Since I do not use them at this time I tried to uninstall `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` via the Ubuntu Software Center. Now whenever I open a console I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader, check that virtualenv has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set properly.
```

Also the directory `~/.virtualenvs/` is still present.

How can I bring my system back to a clean and functional state as before the installation of `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`?

**Updates**

As suggested I checked the following files for occurrences of `virtualenv` each with a negative result:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/*
/etc/environment
```

Comment: Well, you have followed some additional user-specific steps in the installation of virtualenvwrapper. This is outside the scope of the Ubuntu Software Centre. Please include the steps you have followed (perhaps [the official docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction)?). Then we can provide instructions how to revert these steps.

Comment: I can not remember to have done so. Can this result from an installation by `pip`? Unfortunately I do not know whether I used `pip` or the Software Center to install. How can I find out?

Comment: I found it in the history so I am pretty sure I used Software Center instead of `pip`. Anyhow I do not know of any changes I made especially not in reference to the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same issue, but eventually found out where the problematic file was. It's

> /etc/bash_completion.d/virtualenvwrapper

Delete it and you won't see the error message again.

PS: Here's how I found out where the file was:

> grep -lir "virtualenvwrapper" /etc/

Answer (score 1):

You've probably followed this step from [the documentation](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction):

> You will want to add the command to source `/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` to your shell startup file, changing the path to `virtualenvwrapper.sh` depending on where it was installed by `pip`.

Just installing the virtualenvwrapper won't include anything in your shell startup and you would not have got the error in your question on opening a new console.

I cannot guess where exactly you've modified your shell configuration, but if you use Bash, then you've probably put it in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Just remove those lines and try to create a new terminal window.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help! Unfortunately neither of the two files contains the lines you mention. Is there another place where they might be written? I am pretty sure that I never put them anywhere by hand.

Comment: Try `/etc/profile`, files in `/etc/profile.d/` (I think one of those could be it) and `/etc/environment`.

Comment: I checked all of these (see updated question) and there is nothing about `virtualenv` in there. :S